# u'\ufeff' in Python string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I got an error with the following exception message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in
position 155: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Not sure what `u'\ufeff'` is, it shows up when I'm web scraping. How can I remedy the situation? The `.replace()` string method doesn't work on it.

Comment: Where does this input come from? What are you tryring to do? Please include your Python code.

Comment: Incidentally, I find that the .replace() does work in modern python if I remember the unicode indicator: s.replace(u'\ufeff','')

Comment: @DougBradshaw when you say "modern python", do you mean, 2.7+ or 3.0+ ?

Comment: Good point.  Meaning, 2.7+.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

The Unicode character `U+FEFF` is the byte order mark, or BOM, and is used to tell the difference between big- and little-endian UTF-16 encoding.  If you decode the web page using the right codec, Python will remove it for you.  Examples:

```
#!python2
#coding: utf8
u = u'ABC'
e8 = u.encode('utf-8')        # encode without BOM
e8s = u.encode('utf-8-sig')   # encode with BOM
e16 = u.encode('utf-16')      # encode with BOM
e16le = u.encode('utf-16le')  # encode without BOM
e16be = u.encode('utf-16be')  # encode without BOM
print 'utf-8     %r' % e8
print 'utf-8-sig %r' % e8s
print 'utf-16    %r' % e16
print 'utf-16le  %r' % e16le
print 'utf-16be  %r' % e16be
print
print 'utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8     %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8')
print 'utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8-sig')
print 'utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16    %r' % e16.decode('utf-16')
print 'utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16le  %r' % e16.decode('utf-16le')
```

Note that `EF BB BF` is a UTF-8-encoded BOM.  It is not required for UTF-8, but serves only as a signature (usually on Windows).

Output:

```
utf-8     'ABC'
utf-8-sig '\xef\xbb\xbfABC'
utf-16    '\xff\xfeA\x00B\x00C\x00'    # Adds BOM and encodes using native processor endian-ness.
utf-16le  'A\x00B\x00C\x00'
utf-16be  '\x00A\x00B\x00C'

utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8     u'\ufeffABC'    # doesn't remove BOM if present.
utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig u'ABC'          # removes BOM if present.
utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16    u'ABC'          # *requires* BOM to be present.
utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16le  u'\ufeffABC'    # doesn't remove BOM if present.
```

Note that the `utf-16` codec *requires* BOM to be present, or Python won't know if the data is big- or little-endian.

Comment: yes, https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom6

Answer (score 636):

I ran into this on Python 3 and found this question (and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/704616)).
When opening a file, Python 3 supports the encoding keyword to automatically handle the encoding.

Without it, the BOM is included in the read result:

```
>>> f = open('file', mode='r')
>>> f.read()
'\ufefftest'
```

Giving the correct encoding, the BOM is omitted in the result:

```
>>> f = open('file', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
>>> f.read()
'test'
```

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you, this is the actual solution and should be the accepted answer. While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/309917) is great insight on why the string is there, most of the people coming here is looking for a straightforward solution and this is it.

Comment: Had this same issue with the csv DictReader reading a csv file saved from Excel.

Comment: Yes, Excel (even "csv" generated by Excel) really is a hot mess.

Comment: Did not help me to really solve this issue. If I open up the file with this method I still see the `\ufeff`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @MachineLearner, utf-8-sig just worked for me (whew). Is the BOM at the start of your file? I wonder if you can get a hexdump of the bytes. In my case `hexdump -n 16 -C (filename)` produced `00000000  ef bb bf 22 44 61 74 65  22 2c 22 54 69 6d 65 22  |..."Date","Time"|`. The ef bb bf is the UTF-8 encoding of BOM.

Answer (score 8):

That character is the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or "Byte Order Mark".  It is usually received as the first few bytes of a file, telling you how to interpret the encoding of the rest of the data.  You can simply remove the character to continue.  Although, since the error says you were trying to convert to 'ascii', you should probably pick another encoding for whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: the linux command 'dos2unix' can be used to convert both the BOM and line endings to what unix / linux expects.

Answer (score 4):

The content you're scraping is encoded in unicode rather than ascii text, and you're getting a character that doesn't convert to ascii.  The right 'translation' depends on what the original web page thought it was.  [Python's unicode page](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) gives the background on how it works.

Are you trying to print the result or stick it in a file? The error suggests it's *writing* the data that's causing the problem, not reading it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058302/unicode-problems-with-web-pages-in-pythons-urllib) is a good place to look for the fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff'`, happens because Python is trying to encode a character (u'\ufeff', which is the Unicode character for Byte Order Mark or BOM) using the ASCII encoding, which can only represent characters in the range of 0-127. This character is outside of that range, which is why you're seeing this error.

The Byte Order Mark (BOM) is often used to indicate the byte order (endianness) of a text file or stream. It can appear at the beginning of a file that you're scraping from the web if the file is encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or another Unicode format.

Answer (score -1):

Here is based on the answer from Mark Tolonen. The string included different languages of the word 'test' that's separated by '|', so you can see the difference.

```
u = u'ABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
e8 = u.encode('utf-8')        # encode without BOM
e8s = u.encode('utf-8-sig')   # encode with BOM
e16 = u.encode('utf-16')      # encode with BOM
e16le = u.encode('utf-16le')  # encode without BOM
e16be = u.encode('utf-16be')  # encode without BOM
print('utf-8     %r' % e8)
print('utf-8-sig %r' % e8s)
print('utf-16    %r' % e16)
print('utf-16le  %r' % e16le)
print('utf-16be  %r' % e16be)
print()
print('utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8     %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8'))
print('utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8-sig'))
print('utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16    %r' % e16.decode('utf-16'))
print('utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16le  %r' % e16.decode('utf-16le'))
```

Here is a test run:

```
>>> u = u'ABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
>>> e8 = u.encode('utf-8')        # encode without BOM
>>> e8s = u.encode('utf-8-sig')   # encode with BOM
>>> e16 = u.encode('utf-16')      # encode with BOM
>>> e16le = u.encode('utf-16le')  # encode without BOM
>>> e16be = u.encode('utf-16be')  # encode without BOM
>>> print('utf-8     %r' % e8)
utf-8     b'ABCtest\xce\xb2\xe8\xb2\x9d\xe5\xa1\x94\xec\x9c\x84m\xc3\xa1sb\xc3\xaata|test|\xd8\xa7\xd8\xae\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1|\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95|\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6|\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88|\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb7\xe0\xa4\xbe|\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb6\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xa8|\xd7\xa4\xd6\xbc\xd7\xa8\xd7\x95\xd7\x91\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9f|ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra|\xc3\x96l\xc3\xa7ek|'
>>> print('utf-8-sig %r' % e8s)
utf-8-sig b'\xef\xbb\xbfABCtest\xce\xb2\xe8\xb2\x9d\xe5\xa1\x94\xec\x9c\x84m\xc3\xa1sb\xc3\xaata|test|\xd8\xa7\xd8\xae\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1|\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95|\xe6\xb8\xac\xe8\xa9\xa6|\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88|\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb7\xe0\xa4\xbe|\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb6\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xa8|\xd7\xa4\xd6\xbc\xd7\xa8\xd7\x95\xd7\x91\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9f|ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra|\xc3\x96l\xc3\xa7ek|'
>>> print('utf-16    %r' % e16)
utf-16    b"\xff\xfeA\x00B\x00C\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00\xb2\x03\x9d\x8cTX\x04\xc7m\x00\xe1\x00s\x00b\x00\xea\x00t\x00a\x00|\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00|\x00'\x06.\x06*\x06(\x06'\x061\x06|\x00Km\xd5\x8b|\x00,nf\x8a|\x00\xc60\xb90\xc80|\x00*\t0\t@\t\x15\tM\t7\t>\t|\x00*\r0\r?\r6\rK\r'\r(\r|\x00\xe4\x05\xbc\x05\xe8\x05\xd5\x05\xd1\x05\xd9\x05\xe8\x05\xdf\x05|\x00k\x00i\x00\xc3\x1em\x00 \x00t\x00r\x00a\x00|\x00\xd6\x00l\x00\xe7\x00e\x00k\x00|\x00"
>>> print('utf-16le  %r' % e16le)
utf-16le  b"A\x00B\x00C\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00\xb2\x03\x9d\x8cTX\x04\xc7m\x00\xe1\x00s\x00b\x00\xea\x00t\x00a\x00|\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00|\x00'\x06.\x06*\x06(\x06'\x061\x06|\x00Km\xd5\x8b|\x00,nf\x8a|\x00\xc60\xb90\xc80|\x00*\t0\t@\t\x15\tM\t7\t>\t|\x00*\r0\r?\r6\rK\r'\r(\r|\x00\xe4\x05\xbc\x05\xe8\x05\xd5\x05\xd1\x05\xd9\x05\xe8\x05\xdf\x05|\x00k\x00i\x00\xc3\x1em\x00 \x00t\x00r\x00a\x00|\x00\xd6\x00l\x00\xe7\x00e\x00k\x00|\x00"
>>> print('utf-16be  %r' % e16be)
utf-16be  b"\x00A\x00B\x00C\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x03\xb2\x8c\x9dXT\xc7\x04\x00m\x00\xe1\x00s\x00b\x00\xea\x00t\x00a\x00|\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00|\x06'\x06.\x06*\x06(\x06'\x061\x00|mK\x8b\xd5\x00|n,\x8af\x00|0\xc60\xb90\xc8\x00|\t*\t0\t@\t\x15\tM\t7\t>\x00|\r*\r0\r?\r6\rK\r'\r(\x00|\x05\xe4\x05\xbc\x05\xe8\x05\xd5\x05\xd1\x05\xd9\x05\xe8\x05\xdf\x00|\x00k\x00i\x1e\xc3\x00m\x00 \x00t\x00r\x00a\x00|\x00\xd6\x00l\x00\xe7\x00e\x00k\x00|"
>>> print()

>>> print('utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8     %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8'))
utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8     '\ufeffABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
>>> print('utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig %r' % e8s.decode('utf-8-sig'))
utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig 'ABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
>>> print('utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16    %r' % e16.decode('utf-16'))
utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16    'ABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
>>> print('utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16le  %r' % e16.decode('utf-16le'))
utf-16 w/ BOM decoded with utf-16le  '\ufeffABCtestβ貝塔위másbêta|test|اختبار|测试|測試|テスト|परीक्षा|പരിശോധന|פּרובירן|kiểm tra|Ölçek|'
```

It's worth to know that only both `utf-8-sig` and `utf-16` get back the original string after both `encode` and `decode`.

Answer (score -3):

This problem arise basically when you save your python code in a **UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding** because python add some special character at the beginning of the code automatically (which is not shown by the text editors) to identify the encoding format. But, when you try to execute the code it gives you the syntax error in line 1 i.e, start of code because **python compiler understands ASCII encoding**.
when you view the code of file using **read()** function you can see at the begin of the returned code **'\ufeff'** is shown.
The one simplest solution to this problem is just by **changing the encoding back to ASCII encoding**(for this you can copy your code to a notepad and save it Remember! choose the ASCII encoding...
Hope this will help.