# python open file from path generate

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

hi i build path file from a csv file information but in open file error

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\New folder\\a\\\xef\xbb\xbf90305.xlsx'
```

when i print filename show

```
C:\New folder\a\90305.xlsx
```

please help

```
 with open (r'C:\New folder\li.csv','rb')as csvfile:
            spamreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
            for row in spamreader:
                filename = r'C:\New folder\a'
                suffix='.xlsx'
                filename=os.path.join(filename,row[0]+suffix)
                with open(filename,"rb")as fo:
                    print fo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename prefix, `row[0]`, is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded and starts with the Unicode [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

You can use the following to [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string) it:

```
prefix = row[0].decode('utf-8-sig')
filename = os.path.join(filename, prefix + suffix)
```

To read more about encodings, see [7.8.2. Encodings and Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some encoding issues going on. The data from the CSV file is encoded, so open the file using the `codecs` module (Python 2) or specify the encoding when you open the file (Python 3). Assuming UTF8 encoding, and using the `utf-8-sig` codec to take care of any byte order marker (BOM) at the start of the file:

Python 2

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(r'C:\New folder\li.csv','rb', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    etc.
```

Python 3

```
with open(r'C:\New folder\li.csv','rb', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    etc.
```

This assumes that there is only one UTF8 BOM and that it occurs at the beginning of the file, not at random points in the file. You are using windows, so that is not a bad assumption.