# API doesn't work. (IP-API)

Tags: api, geo

I wanted the IP-API resolve the IP that I got in the first link, but it does not work.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import sys
    import requests
    print "Conectando com %s" % sys.argv[1]
    Get_Skype   =   requests.get("http://api.predator.wtf/resolver/?arguments=%s" % sys.argv[1]).text
    print "Entrando em %s" % Get_Skype
    My_API      =   requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/%s" % Get_Skype).text
    print My_API
```

Command Line:

```
    $ python script.py user_skype
```

The api returns:

```
    {"message":"invalid query","query":"<ip>","status":"fail"}
```

Comment: What does `print "Entrando em %s" % Get_Skype` print ?

Answer (score 1):

The result of the request "http://api.predator.wtf/resolver/?arguments=user_skype" which is stored in `Get_Skype` is

> Crap, No IP Was Found!

and not a valid IP which causes your api consider it a bad query (which it actually is). So you probably should first check this result being a valid IP address, before passing it to API.

If a valid username is entered, the result of the `predator` query has a trailing `\ufeff` character, which is [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string) how to deal with it.

Comment: It is an example, if you put a valid Skype user will run correctly.

Comment: Two last lines of the answer

Comment: Now found! Thank you!