# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character X at position Y: character maps to undefined

Tags: python, encoding

**To CLARIFY: this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string), I have already tried all the hints there and didn't get the answer.**

I have a txt file with unicode data in, and am want to open the file as an string.

I tried

```
a=open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
print a.read()
```

but there is an error saying:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' at
>   position Y: character maps to undefined

Now my question is, I don't care about my UTF-8 characters at all, is there anyway to put an exception that whenever python is encountering utf-8 character just remove it or pass it?   **Also to clarify, I have tried the encoding with, utf-8, utf-8-sig, utf-16 and etc.**

I tried this as well but no luck.

```
a=open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
try:
    print a.read()
except:
    pass
```

I also tried importing codecs and the code below:

```
a=codecs.open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
print a.read()
```

but still same error is popping out.

Comment: From that post `utf-8  w/ BOM decoded with utf-8-sig u'ABC'          # removes BOM if present.`

Comment: @Leb its not a duplicated of that, I already tried the hints there and didn't work for me, I have tried both utf-8 and utf-8-sig

Comment: You should include that in your question then. Otherwise we can't tell what you tried or didn't try.

Comment: you are right, I will add a edition now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcting my answer for encoding in `print` statement:
Avoid printing to `stdout` Windows, because Python assumes that CMD terminal can only handle Windows-1252 (MS copy of ISO of latin-1). This is easily sidestepped by always printing to `stderr` instead:

```
import sys
print('your text', file=sys.stderr)
```

On Linux there should be no issue with printing Unicode correctly.

**P.S.:** for Python 2.x:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print('your text', file=sys.stderr)
```

**P.P.S.:**
 **Original answer:**
For python 3.x:

```
a=open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers for a detailed list of your options

Comment: This will handle *decode* errors from the *file*. The asker is having *encode* problems on *output*.