# Python error when calling column data from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was practicing to import stock market data from Google Finance into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series

path = 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=542029859096076&startdate=Sep+22%2C+2001&enddate=Sep+20%2C+2016&num=30&ei=3HvhV4n3D8XGmAGp4q74Ag&output=csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

So far so good, and df also shows the complete data set I need.

However, when calling particular columns, like

```
df['Date']
```

Python shows the error codes below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-cb486dd31fbc>", line 1, in <module>
    df['Date']

  File "/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)

  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)

  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)

  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)

KeyError: 'Date'
```

On the other hand, other columns such as df['High'] turns out to be okay. Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

Comment: It works fine when I try.

Comment: (Based on MaxU's answer, it probably works fine because I use Python 3.5).

Comment: @ayhan, did `df['Date']` work for you??? It shouldn't work also under Python 3.5...

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5 too

Comment: @MaxU yes, it worked: http://imgur.com/tmRLNQu

Comment: @MaxU I also upgraded to 0.19.0rc1, could that be the reason?

Comment: @ayhan, aha, i gues Pandas team has improved it!

Comment: @ayhan, thank you for the hint! I've added an excerpt from what's new 0.19.0 to my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this CSV file contains [BOM (Byte Order Mark) signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string), so try it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

How one can easily identify this problem (thanks to [@jezrael's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601251/python-error-when-calling-column-data-from-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment66511340_39601325)):

```
In [11]: print(df.columns.tolist())
['\ufeffDate', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
```

and pay attention at the first column

**NOTE:** as [@ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601251/python-error-when-calling-column-data-from-pandas-dataframe/39601325#comment66511256_39601251) has noticed, starting with version 0.19.0 [Pandas will take care of it automatically](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html):

Bug in pd.read_csv() which caused BOM files to be incorrectly parsed by not ignoring the BOM [GH4793](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4793)

Comment: Hey thanks! It works fine this way. Can you explain a bit more about why it makes the difference or point me to some sources about BOM signature? Thanks again.

Comment: Nicer and better see if use `print(df.columns.tolist())`, +1