# encoding an url with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urlencode

I'm trying to use generated URLs like this one
[http://www.viaf.org/viaf/search?query=cql.any+=+%22Jean-Claude%20Moissinac%22&maximumRecords=5&httpAccept=application/json](http://www.viaf.org/viaf/search?query=cql.any%20=%20%22Jean-Claude%20Moissinac%22&maximumRecords=5&httpAccept=application/json)

but when using it with

```html
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
# successful trial with the URI
urlQuery = u'http://www.viaf.org/viaf/search?query=cql.any%20=%20"Bacache%20Maya"&httpAccept=application%2Fjson&maximumRecords=5'
print(urlQuery)
req = urllib.request.Request(urlQuery)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as rep:
  print("success")

# attempt to build the URI; request fails
viafBaseUrl = u"http://www.viaf.org"
viafCommand = u"/viaf/search?"
viafSearchTemplate = u'"__name%20__surname"'
name = u"Bacache"
surname = u"Maya"
searchString = u'cql.any%20=%20' + viafSearchTemplate.replace(u"__surname", surname).replace(u"__name", name)
params = u"query="+searchString+u"&httpAccept=application%2Fjson&maximumRecords=5"
computedQuery = viafBaseUrl + viafCommand + params
print(urlQuery)
if computedQuery==urlQuery:
  print("same strings")
req = urllib.request.Request(computedQuery)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as rep:
  print("success")
```

The first request is successful, while the second fails with this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 76: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried a lot of ways to work around the problem without success.
Using `urllib.parse.urlencode()` fails because it changes some chars which must remains intact.

The result of the print on both url is identical, but the strings are different, but I don't understand how to get the same strings.

Comment: Read this post..http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/6107715

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden unicode character in the string `application﻿%2F` between `n` and `%`. Just delete it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your second print statement you are accidentally referencing the first query `urlQuery` instead of `computedQuery`. There's an extra space in the computed query which becomes obvious after fixing the print statement.

Updated code below with the fixes and a couple comments:

```html
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
# successful trial with the URI
urlQuery = u'http://www.viaf.org/viaf/search?query=cql.any%20=%20"Bacache%20Maya"&httpAccept=application%2Fjson&maximumRecords=5'
print(urlQuery)
req = urllib.request.Request(urlQuery)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as rep:
  print("success")

# attempt to build the URI; request fails
viafBaseUrl = u"http://www.viaf.org"
viafCommand = u"/viaf/search?"
viafSearchTemplate = u'"__name%20__surname"'
name = u"Bacache"
surname = u"Maya"
searchString = u'cql.any%20=%20' + viafSearchTemplate.replace(u"__surname", surname).replace(u"__name", name)
params = u"query="+searchString+u"&httpAccept=application﻿%2Fjson&maximumRecords=5" # space after application deleted
computedQuery = viafBaseUrl + viafCommand + params
print(computedQuery) # was urlQuery
if computedQuery==urlQuery:
  print("same strings")
req = urllib.request.Request(computedQuery)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as rep:
  print("success")
```