# urlopen doesn't appear to work depending on how input text is generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, unicode

For some reason or another, it appears that depending on where I copy and paste a url from, urllib.request.urlopen won't work. For example when I copy http://www.google.com/ from the address bar and run the following script:

```
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.google.com/"

response = request.urlopen(url)
print(response)
```

I get the following error at the call to urlopen:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

But if I copy the url string from text on a web page or type it out by hand, it works just fine. To be clear, this doesn't work

```
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.google.com/"

response = request.urlopen(url)
print(response)

#url1 = "http://www.google.com/"
#
#response1 = request.urlopen(url1)
#print(response1)
```

but this does:

```
from urllib import request

#url = "http://www.google.com/"
#
#response = request.urlopen(url)
#print(response)

url1 = "http://www.google.com/"

response1 = request.urlopen(url1)
print(response1)
```

My suspicion is that the encoding is different in the actual address bar, and Spyder knows how to handle it, but I don't because I can't see what is actually going on.

EDIT: As requested...

print(ascii(url))
'http://www.google.com/\ufeff'

print(ascii(url1))
'http://www.google.com/'

Indeed the strings are different.

Comment: To see the difference in your strings, post the results of `print(ascii(url))` and `print(ascii(url1))`, because visually, there is no difference in your code.

Comment: Edited the question to show print(ascii(url)) and print(ascii(url1)). Upon research this is the byte order mark. For some reason when I copy from my browser's address bar, it adds the BOM, but now when I copy from web page text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.google.com/"

response = request.urlopen(url.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\ufeff", ""))
print(response)
```

That Unicode character is the byte-order mark or BOM (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string)) you can encode without BOM by using `utf-8-sig` decoding then replacing the problematic character

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that and I get another error: 

"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'"

I checked what actually gets passed into urlopen and it is the following:

b'http://www.google.com/\xef\xbb\xbf'

Comment: @jamesthelames I just tested it out myself and those revisions seemed to fix it

Comment: Copied and pasted your code with no luck. I found that simply doing url.replace("\ufeff","") worked though: 
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.google.com/".replace("\ufeff", "")

response = request.urlopen(url)
print(response)

Comment: @jamesthelames weird it worked for me. I guess it's difficult to replicate exactly because I can't copy and paste the url the same way you could. Glad you got it to work though.

Comment: Yeah, it is a weird problem indeed. Marked as answer for getting me pretty much 95% of the way there and explaining the BOM. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`\ufeff` is a zero-width non-breaking space, so it's no wonder you can't see it. Yes, there's an invisible character in your URL. At least it's not gremlins.