# Openpyxl Unicode decode error cannot remove \ufeff from cell value

Tags: unicode, utf-8, decode, openpyxl

I am parsing multiple worksheets of unicode data and creating a dictionary for specific cells in each sheet but I am having trouble decoding the unicode data.  The small snippet of the code is below

```
for key in shtDict:
    sht = wb[key] 
    for row in sht.iter_rows('A:A',row_offset = 1):
        for cell in row:
            if isinstance(cell.value,unicode):
                if "INC" in cell.value:
                    shtDict[key] = cell.value
```

The output of this section is:

```
{'60071508': u'\ufeffReason: INC8595939', '60074426': u'\ufeffReason. Ref INC8610481', '60071539': u'\ufeffReason: INC8603621'}
```

I tried to properly decode the data based on [u'\ufeff' in Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string), by changing the last line to:

```
shtDict[key] = cell.value.decode('utf-8-sig')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 55, in <module>
    shtDict[key] = cell.value.decode('utf-8-sig')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8_sig.py", line 22, in decode
    (output, consumed) = codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Not sure what the issue is, I have also tried decoding with 'utf-16', but I get the same error.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You use `decode()` to go from an encoded string to unicode. Hence, you don't need to try and decode anything that is already unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it simpler: you can ignore BOF, so just ignore BOF characters.

```
shtDict[key] = cell.value.replace(u'\ufeff', '', 1)
```

Note: `cell.value` is already unicode type (you just checked it), so you cannot decode it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the note.  Still trying to get a better grasp on Unicode encoding and decoding