# Python 'ascii' codec can't encode character error

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec

I was trying to read utf-16 file. This code is working fine on local machine but when I ran it on AWS Batch service then it's giving above error.

```
import codecs
file_to_split = codecs.open("file_utf_16.txt", 'r+', "UTF-16")
```

It throws an exception `header 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: the file needs to be decoded with `utf-16le` not `utf-16`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first few bytes are the BOM (Byte Order Mark). This is a sequence of bytes at the beginning of a Unicode document that tells you the byte order, encoding, etc.

This Wikipedia article will help explain the technical details:

[Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

You have a couple of choices. This answer shows various methods of handling BOM for different encodings: [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/8016720)

And this answer shows you how to properly read the file into memory, which is what I think that you want to do. [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150749/8016720). This way you can then process the file as a normal Python string.