# Scraping list of URLs in CSV is giving unknown URL Type Error

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to scrape a list of URLs stored in a CSV file. A sample URL has the following form:

```
http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/amazon-instant-video-browser/
```

I now get the following error, if I am trying to parse the URL list to Beautifulsoup:

```
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ﻿http>
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this problem? I think it might be an easy fix, but I cannot work it out. Here is the code I am currently using:

```py
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('url.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: which url is having an error? can you give us more sample data in url.csv?

Comment: use `print(url)` and `print( url[0] )` to see what you use.

Comment: you can do `contents = list( csv.reader(csvf) )`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I tried what you mentioned with the `contents = list( csv.reader(csvf) )` but now I am getting the error `TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator`. Have you an idea on why this could happened?

Comment: Here are the five first URLs which have been printed: `['\ufeffhttp://mashable.com/2013/01/07/amazon-instant-video-browser/']
['http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/ap-samsung-sponsored-tweets/']
['http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/apple-40-billion-app-downloads/']
['http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/astronaut-notre-dame-bcs/']
['http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/att-u-verse-apps/']`. It seems that the first URL is wrong. How can I remove the `\ufeff`?

Comment: Take a look in this question to remove `u'\ufeff'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string

Answer (score 0):

Use Try and except within your For loop to avoid any http error. For eg. :

```
for url in urls:
       **try:**
         contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
       **except:
         pass**
for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
       **try:**
         page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
         soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
       **except:
         pass**
```