# Strange characters, Python said TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length X found

Tags: python, character, special-characters

I just found a set of strange characters that I've never seen before from someone (https://paste.villavu.com/show/2991/) (the chars are separated by a space). That person said a char from that characters set can be used to make a person's name field blank in Twitch, Discord, etc, so they will show like they have no name.

I've tried to figure out what those chars really are by using Python's `ord()`. But I got `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length X found` although I only put 1 char for the `ord()` argument and all things seem valid.

I'm taking a char from that character set, and try to put it in `ord()`

```
>>> ord('﻿ ﻿')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

Then I continued by assuming that strange char is a set of chars.

```
>>> '﻿ ﻿'[0]
'\ufeff'
>>> '﻿ ﻿'[1]
' '
>>> '﻿ ﻿'[2]
'\ufeff'
```

From what I've found `\ufeff` is a byte order mark (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string)). But still it doesn't make sense to me, especially about how those chars can be packed together so it seems like it is only like 1 character from my computer.

And why some platforms treat it as a valid value, e.g for name.

Anybody could explain to me about this please?

Comment: I see nothing besides numbers 1-22 on your first link

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you except to say that your string is 3 distinct characters with valid encoding, which you've already noticed. `[ord(i) for i in ' ']` gives `[65279, 32, 65279]`, and the purposes of this character are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string) which you've already found

Comment: As to why It's allowed: because the character is valid, it's that simple. This is one of many reasons why inputs for text fields should be validated in any sort of application

Comment: You’ve established that Python considers your text to be multiple characters; why do you think it’s only one?

Comment: @Reedinationer you have to select them, they're mostly invisible characters like space

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks

Comment: @DavisHerring Because I can select it with my mouse, and it looks like I'm only selecting one char. Btw, I just remembered, I guess it's similar to how zalgo texts and Asian scripts (esp. [Thai](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5362200)) are created (they look like a char, but it's actually a string, they just get rendered stacked)

Comment: @RafidAslam: Indeed: what Python considers a “character” is actually a code point; what the user considers a character is usually a “grapheme cluster”, and composition and canonicalization change the number of one without changing the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from its use as a BOM (already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083336/strange-characters-python-said-typeerror-ord-expected-a-character-but-strin#comment98805314_56083336)), U+FEFF is also the (deprecated) [ZWNBSP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space), which is why it is hard to detect by pointer selection.  As it is (or has been) used in running text, it is plausible to accept it in a username, but obviously such usage can be confusing (as for a lot of Unicode characters).