# Python - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeeff0'

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read from 2 text files (001.txt and temp.txt) and compare the numbers. I am opening the files, reading from them, and using int() to convert the strings to ints. The files only contain a single number, 0 for both in this case. I am getting the error `ValueErrorr: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff0'`. I have checked the text files and there are no spaces or extra lines. I am not sure what the issue is. Any advice would be much appreciated!

code:

```
localfile = open("001.txt", "r") 
local_num = localfile.read()
tempfile_name = "temp.txt"
tempfile = open(tempfile_name, "r")
if(int(local_num) == int(temp_num)):
    print("same")
elif(int(local_num) != int(temp_num)):
    print("different")
tempfile.close()
localfile.close()
```

Comment: specify encoding when opening the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [u'\ufeff' in Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string), specifically the second answer should help you.

Comment: @erich THANK YOU! Once i added "encoding='uft-8-sig" it worked!

Answer (score 1):

May be as simple as this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    file1_num = int(file1.readline().strip())
    file2_num = int(file2.readline().strip())

if(int(file1_num) == int(file2_num)):
    print("same")
else:
    print("different")
```

Actually you can open multiple files in the same line, this would make the code look a little cleaner! Hope that helps!

Comment: I did this and did what Erich mentioned and it worked! I had to add "encoding='utf-8-sig'" when I opened the files. Thank you!

Comment: @Swollos, glad!