# Project Gutenberg accessing text with url

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, project-gutenberg

I'm trying to access a text file from project gutenberg's url.
Hence I've copyed the same code from nltk book's, the result was different.

```
from urllib import request
url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt"
response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read().decode('utf8')
raw[:75]
```

This was from nltk book. When it worked properly, it should print out,

```
’The Project Gutenberg EBook of Crime and Punishment, by Fyodor Dostoevsky\r\n’
```

But when I tried the same on my computer, it came out with this,

```
'\ufeffThe Project Gutenberg EBook of Crime and Punishment, by Fyodor Dostoevsky\r'
```

I think it's a problem with the headers in project gutenberg. Could you help me how to deal with this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string

Answer (score 2):

The URL response text seems encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.

Try:

```sh
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt"

response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read()
text = raw.decode("utf-8-sig")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811) for more information