# Create a dictionary from a CSV file produces \ufeff characters

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, encoding, utf-16

I want to read data from a CSV file. The content of CVS file is

```
rekindle relight 
pesky annoying

Cell A1 contains rekindle
Cell B1 contains relight
Cell A2 contains pesky 
Cell B2 contains annoying
```

After reading the contain of the file I want to create a dictionary. The name of the dictionary is words_meanings. The name of the csv file is "words.csv"

```
import csv
file_name="words.csv"
words_meanings = {}
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        key, value = line.split(",")
        words_meanings[key] = value.rstrip("\n")
print(words_meanings)
```

The output was : `{'\ufeffrekindle': 'relight', 'pesky': 'annoying'}` I want to removed `\ufeff` portion from the output. So I rewrite the code

```
import csv
file_name="words.csv"
words_meanings = {}
with open(file_name, newline='', encoding='utf-16-le') as file:

    for line in file.readlines():
        key, value = line.split(",")
        words_meanings[key] = value.rstrip("\n")
print(words_meanings)
```

Now I get `'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 0: truncated data` error.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: you can find more info similar to yours in the first answer here [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/5568212)

Comment: Thank you Adam. This is such a great help.