# Clean headers and remove bold text

Tags: django-import-export, tablib

I have a CSV that has bold text on all of the first columns. I wanted to sanitize it first since now it failed to get the row I wanted to get.

I tried printing the row in `before_import_row` and this is how it looks like.

`('\ufeffaccount_number', '000-152-1808')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using [dynamic columns](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#dynamic-columns) in tablib.  Add a callable which returns the unsanitized column value, and then add it to a new column.

```py
def accno_cleaned(row):
    return '\ufeffaccount_number'

def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
    dataset.append_col(accno_cleaned, header='account_number')
```

However I think it might be better to sanitize the data before it gets imported into django-import-export if you can because this will be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: I'll accept this thank you, but I fixed my issue by following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string/17912811#17912811, basically changing the decode from UTF-8 to utf-8-sig