# Python adding extra text and braces while reading from CSV file

Tags: python, selenium, csv, data-manipulation, data-mining

I wanted to read data from a csv file using python but after using the following code there are some extra characters and braces in the text which is not in the original data.
Please help to remove it.

```
import csv

with open("data.csv",encoding="utf8") as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

[image: screenshot of orignal data]

What is displayed after reading is:- **['\ufeffwww.aslteramo.it']**

Comment: This is a duplicate question of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string/17912811#17912811

Comment: Does this answer your question? [u'\ufeff' in Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string)

Comment: What are you using to view the file? Also, how are you running Python?  Not everything can display utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 1):

This is utf-8 encoding with a Byte Order Mark (BOM) - which is used as a signature in windows.

Open the file using the `utf-8-sig` encoding instead of `utf8`

Answer (score 0):

`\ufeff` is a UTF-8 BOM (also known as ['ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) character).

It's sometimes used to indicate that the file is in UTF-8 format.

You could use `str.replace('\ufeff', '')` in your code to get rid of it. Like this:

```py
import csv

with open("data.csv",encoding="utf8") as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        print([col.replace('\ufeff', '') for col in row])
```

Another solution is to open the file with 'utf-8-sig' encoding instead of 'utf-8' encoding.

By the way, the braces are a added because `row` is a list. If your CSV file only has one column, you could select the first item from each row like this:

```py
print(row[0].replace('\ufeff', ''))
```